# Using the X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION header for TransactionSearch in PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, permissions, paypal-sandbox, signature

I'm using the PayPal API to Request Permissions from a merchant to access certain parts of their accout. One of these is the TransactionSearch method.

Normally using TransactionSearch is possible only when providing a USER, PWD, and SIGNATURE. However, I don't have access to that information from a merchant when using PayPal's Permissions service. The only information I have consists of:

- a request token,
- a verification code,
- an access token,
- a token secret
- the generated signature (I'm assuming I generated this correctly)

Using this information, I put together the following `X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION` header:

`X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION:timestamp=1337848711,
token=DmyRT4TygwxPvfNExkH29I53S1il6yTmsJFwXRT7jLjaYyezOfUmnQ,
signature=sphzCP0H47JTDJS8uuMsqWHAIAo=`

So in the case of `TransactionSearch`, how can I use the information above to get the transactions I'm looking for? I can, of course, use my own `USER`, `PWD`, and `SIGNATURE`, but that only gives me my own transactions, even if I user the `X-PAYPAL_AUTHORIZATION` header. I need those of the merchant who I just got permissions from.

Comment: how did you create signature? Using PHP? If so please share the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are acting on behalf of a third party, you need to include a SUBJECT field in your data request and pass the email of the third party merchant. If you have authenticated with this merchant, you should get their information. In Python (sorry - don't have a PHP example) these are the fields I'm passing in as part of my data (not my header). My header is empty.

```
return [('VERSION', self.api_version),  # This is 84 for me.
        ('user', self.api_username),  # This is *your* username.
        ('PWD', self.api_password),  # This is *your* password
        ('SIGNATURE', self.api_signature),  # This is *your* signature.
        ('SUBJECT', self.subject)]  # This is the third party's email.
```

Note that this doesn't use the key at all, which is sort of out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! This finally allows me to get the transactions of another merchant. So why does PayPal even give you back an authorization token and a token secret if they aren't even used?

Comment: There are a lot of PayPal peculiarities. It feels like maybe three different teams wrote APIs that are now "The API."